# add string to the beginning of a file and another string to the end of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

this is my file

```
$ cat testjson2
[alot of text]
```

I would like to end up with below: (`{ "aaData":` append at the start of the file `}` appended at the end of the file)

```
{ "aaData": [alot of text] }
```

What I have got so far:

this does the appending at the start of the file

```
$ sed '1s/./{ "aaData": &/' testjson2
{ "aaData": [alot of text] }
```

this does the appending at the end of the file

```
$ echo } >> testjson2
$ cat testjson2
[alot of text]
}
```

**How do I combine them? maybe just using sed or should i just use this combination to get what I want?**
just looking at using sed awk or bash here.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed '1s/^/{ "aaData": /; $ s/$/ }/' testjson2
{ "aaData": [alot of text] }
```

This uses two substitute commands:

- `1 s/^/{ "aaData": /` adds text to the beginning of the first line.

  `1` matches on line 1.  `^` matches on the beginning of a line.
- `$ s/$/ }/` adds text after the end of the last line.

  The first `$` matches the last line of the file.  The second `$` matches at the end of a the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? ORS : "{ \"aaData\": "), $0} END{print " }"}' file
{ "aaData": [alot of text] }
```

Comment: tks @ed. can you just give a brief explanation? what i know, `NR>1` on the first line, `? ORS` not sure output record  separator, `END{print " }"}` is END the last line? , `printf "%s%s"` is the first %s for the first string at the start and the second %s for the 2nd string `}` to append at the end?